Transparent line at the top in the titlebar
Transparent line (1px size) at the top in the titlebar. Help me fix this please.


System:
Kubuntu
Ubuntu version: 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)
plasmashell 6.1.5
Similar questions: 1
